# Convert attribute into string

Tags: javascript, string, variables, attributes

I know this is really basic javascript but I'm really not so familiar with javascript.

What I'm trying here is to add prettyPhoto arguments where I want to be. First I get href attribute from link, then I convert it to string, then I take last 4 letters to check is it link to image or to some HTML page. And this code works fine but still my Firebug sends me an error:

TypeError: **$hrefy** is undefined

```
txt = $hrefy.toString();
```

How script can work if $hrefy is not defined and how to define it well. This error blocks only javascript code for filtering my portfolio, while other js work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

$hrefy = $("article a").has('img').attr("href");
txt = $hrefy.toString();
var lastChar = txt.substr(txt.length - 4);
if (lastChar=='.jpg') {
    $('article a').has('img').attr('data-rel', 'prettyPhoto'); 
}

$('a img').click(function () {  
    var desc = $(this).attr('title');  
    $('a').has('img').attr('title', desc);  
});
```

});

Comment: It already is a string.

Comment: Why are `$hrefy` and `txt` global variables? Do they need to be? Add `var` before them if they don't.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `$hrefy = $("#article a > img").parent().attr("href");`?

Comment: You can check page where problem is http://valeka.net/karen/page-a

Comment: You are trying to retrieve the `href` property from the `img` elements, but the `href` is not a valid property for that element. You use `href` in the a `tag` to create hyperlinks. Don't you want to retrieve the `a` elements?

Comment: Marcus, you're mistaken about how has() works.

Comment: No @MarcusVinicius, I'm getting right property, you can check it on pages  [link](http://valeka.net/karen/post-format-test-image-attached/) and  [link](http://valeka.net/karen/images-test/2/), I added alert for this value to show.

Comment: Yeah, I was mistaken, it returns the `a` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source of the page you've linked, I've noticed that there is no `<article>` element declared anywhere. So, your jquery selector does not return anything and `attr('href')` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've couldnt ever solve this by myself! Thanks again!